# How to style Angular Material mat-form-field/matInput

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm using the latest angular material version(v16) and I'm trying to style the matInput(inside a mat-form-field) and I'm having some issues with the behaviour. I simply want to override the color of the input when I haven't touched. I also want to change the placeholder and mat-label color.

What solutions do I have to only change the color of the border but not affect the behaviour of material component?

I've found a solution with ng-deep that works partially, but the style remains applied even the inputs have error or is focused. It keeps this green color for border always, but if there are errors I want to have the border of red color, if it's focused I want to have the default color for focused(blue in this case).

```
::ng-deep .mdc-notched-outline__leading {
  border-color: green !important;
}
::ng-deep .mdc-notched-outline__notch {
  border-color: green !important;
}
::ng-deep .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-color: green !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would not use ng:deep its deprecated, you need to override the style

style.scss

```
// Default state
mat-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
  color: green;
}

// Focused state
mat-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused .mat-form-field-outline {
  color: blue; // or whatever color you want
}

// Error state
mat-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-outline {
  color: red;
}

// Placeholder and label
mat-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-label {
  color: green; // Change as needed
}
```

if the above not working add additional class

```
<mat-form-field class="custom-mat-input">
  <mat-label>Label</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
</mat-form-field>

.custom-mat-input.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
  color: green;
}
// ... and so on for other states
```

Comment: This doesn't have any effect on style.